# Cannot see javascript files in Monodevelop Unity 5.2

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Since upgrading to Unity 5.2 javascript (unityscript) files are not showing in the Monodevelop Solution explorer (see image below). Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Might they be in the Assembly-CSharp-Editor-firstpass project?

Comment: I have looked in all of the folders, not appearing in Scripts where they are in the folder structure

Comment: Also, intellisense does not appear to be working for unityscript either.

Comment: Have you tried to  click the js file in Unity3D and make the MonoDevelop the default program to open it? You can get clues from there.

Comment: Are the files still visible in Unity3D? What happens if you try to open them from Unity3D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed these same issues with the following steps.

**Create Backup**

Make a copy of your project folder in case something is mistakenly deleted.

**Delete Scripting Files**

In the root of your project folder, delete only the following files:

- Files beginning with `Assembly-`
- Files beginning with your project name, i.e. `kickoff3d01`

**Sync Scripts**

In the Unity Editor, go to `Assets` -> `Sync MonoDevelop Project`.

**Locate in MonoDevelop**

In MonoDevelop, they should be listed under `Assembly-UnityScript`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't have a "Sync MonoDevelop Project" option, but I was able to solve the issue by going to Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor